# how to use MIN and MAX sql query in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

i want to use `min` and `max` laravel elaquent at the same line, is that posible?

```
Appointmentsetting::where('Day','=',1)
->whereIn('PersonID', function ($query) {
    $query->select('p.id')
        ->from('users as p')
        ->join('appointmentsettings as aps', 'aps.PersonID', '=', 'p.id')
        ->where('p.active', '=', 1)
        ->where('aps.CompanyID', '=', 1)
        ->orWhereIn('aps.PersonID', function ($query2) {
            $query2->select('cps.user_id')
                    ->from('companypersonstructs as cps')
                    ->where('cps.CompanyID', '=', 1);
        })
        ->groupBy('aps.PersonID');
})
->where('active', '=', 1)
->select(\DB::raw("SELECT MIN(StartFrom) AS StartFrom, MAX(EndTo) AS EndTo"));
->get();
```

i got error

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT
>   MIN(StartFrom) AS StartFrom, MAX(EndTo) AS EndTo from
>   `appointmentsetting' at line 1

Comment: min('col_name')->max('col_name') ?

Comment: ->select(DB::raw("MIN(StartFrom) AS StartFrom, MAX(EndTo) AS EndTo"))  Try This

Comment: @LimKeanPhang yeah i already try it but the system give me error `Call to a member function max() on string`

Comment: Updated comments. Try DB::raw

Comment: just remove SELECT form inside

Comment: @GauravGupta how is it?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#raw-expressions more detail , when you use selectRaw() so why need extra select

Comment: @LimKeanPhang it send me builder result `Builder {#590 ▼
  #query: Builder {#591 ▶}
  #model: Appointmentsetting {#592 ▶}
  #eagerLoad: []
  #localMacros: []
  #onDelete: null
  #passthru: array:13 [▶]
  #scopes: []
  #removedScopes: []
}`

Comment: please update little more code also

Comment: @GauravGupta done, please take a look

Comment: sorry, i still get same error as above when i change to `DB::RAW`

Comment: ->select(\DB::raw("MIN(StartFrom) AS StartFrom, MAX(EndTo) AS EndTo")); //Remove the additional select inside @Jazuly

Comment: ->selectRaw(" MIN(StartFrom) AS StartFrom, MAX(EndTo) AS EndTo");  put this please and try

Comment: @LimKeanPhang its work, thanks, please write u answer.

Comment: btw, my first code its works too just need remove select inside the code.

Comment: Alright~Done. Cheers~!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Appointmentsetting::where('Day','=',1)
->whereIn('PersonID', function ($query) {
    $query->select('p.id')
        ->from('users as p')
        ->join('appointmentsettings as aps', 'aps.PersonID', '=', 'p.id')
        ->where('p.active', '=', 1)
        ->where('aps.CompanyID', '=', 1)
        ->orWhereIn('aps.PersonID', function ($query2) {
            $query2->select('cps.user_id')
                    ->from('companypersonstructs as cps')
                    ->where('cps.CompanyID', '=', 1);
        })
        ->groupBy('aps.PersonID');
})
->where('active', '=', 1)
->select(\DB::raw("MIN(StartFrom) AS StartFrom, MAX(EndTo) AS EndTo"));
->get();
```

Answer (score 6):

```
->selectRaw(" MIN(StartFrom) AS StartFrom, MAX(EndTo) AS EndTo");
```

please put above query and try. the main problem in your query is you are using select two time there is no need for write select inside select or selectRaw 
for more about raw query click [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#raw-expressions)

Comment: i was writing information both time in comment as well as in answer that why i didn't see it comment and answer is already there